# I Transfered Bitcoin without synchronizing Bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am very new to bitcoin wallets and to all and I really need help for anyone who can help me. I just transfered bitcoin from my LocalBitcoin site to JUST downloaded Bitcoin Core wallet. I didnt know about synchronizing until I sent bitcoins to there.  I went to receive address and got an address. The problem I have is I have a LENOVO PAD which does NOT have the memory to download the whole BLOCKCHAIN.  I stays currently 3years 2 weeks behind.  And it seems it will not be able to download.  How do I get back my coins to LocalBitcoins and PLEASE ANY HELP WILL BE GOOOD.

thank you in advance